# How to change the background color of webpage randomly using a json api?

Tags: javascript, html, json

I want to execute a javascript onload to change the background color of the webpage randomly based on this json file which gives the random color.

http://api.creativehandles.com/getRandomColor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// this function will be triggered when the page loads. Every time you refresh the page a new background color will be set because this function will be invoked 
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
   // fetch is in charge of getting the data from the API
   fetch('http://api.creativehandles.com/getRandomColor') // Call the fetch function passing the url of the API as a parameter
.then(function(response) {

             response.json().then(function(data){
                 let color = data["color"]; 
                document.body.style.backgroundColor = color;
             })

         })
.catch(function() {
    // This is where you run code if the server returns any errors
});
})
```

You could also extract all the fetch logic into a separate function and create a button which call the function on click thus changing the background color every time you click the button

Comment: did you test it? However this is not working for me

Comment: I just updated the answer and tested it. It works, try it now. Let me know if you have any other questions regarding the code that were not covered by my comments. Sorry it wasn't working before, I wrote the answer from my phone and couldn't tested it